# Laravel give array to route, not all values are required

Tags: php, laravel

**I'm getting this error**

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: payment.checkPayment] [URI: {unique_link}/{paymentrequest}/{info}].
```

Here I encode the array. `Note` is optional, is also nullable in database.

```
$info = json_encode(["name" => $request->name, "note" => $request->note]);
```

This is where I'm sending it to the route

```
route('payment.checkPayment', [$uniquelink, $paymentrequest, $info])
```

Route

```
Route::get('/{unique_link}/{paymentrequest}/{info}', ['as' => 'payment.checkPayment', 'uses' => 'PaymentController@checkPayment']);
```

How would I fix this? It seems to me I'm sending all of the parameters.

Comment: Not sure about this but {unique_link} and $uniquelink might be interpreted as different variables because if the underscore in the first one?

Comment: @NickSurmanidze Nope, this changed nothing unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use key-value arrays instead of array-lists as you do:

use:

```
route('payment.checkPayment', ['unique_link'=>$uniquelink, 'paymentrequest'=>$paymentrequest, 'info'=>$info]);
```

Reference [Laravel Named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)

**NOTE** it seems you use `json-encoded` value for the `info` field, but NOT SURE if this will **generate a valid URI**. Better check it.